# Flutter local_auth issues on android certain devices

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt

I'm currently having issues with local_auth on certain devices: LG-G6 (Android 7.0) and Samsung Galaxy J7 Pro (Both running on android 7), and i believe there's more android devices having this issue.

Authentication always fails on the **authenticateWithBiometrics** function:

> //Always failes here:

> var localAuth = LocalAuthentication(); bool didAuthenticate =
> await localAuth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
> localizedReason: 'Please authenticate.');

But again, it's only failing on the above mentioned devices.
I checked on 3 project that are currently using local auth and they also failing, even the developers of those projects where not aware.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the Android project, on styles.xml

i replaced:

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

With:

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

After debugging the app with the devices that had issues i realised that it was throwing a platform exception and complaining about the **Theme.AppCompat** that is missing.

Hope this helps anyone who faces the same issue

Comment: I applied this but not working. I am facing the issue in oppo phones.